# wicket form tester - formTester.submit() behaves differently than "real" wicket submit

Tags: java, wicket

When I submit a form in real wicket the onInitialize() is called for my component, but when I submit with the wicket tester (more specifically with the FormTester) the onInitialize() of the component is NOT called.

That caused some disturbance when we encountered that our forms weren't working, even though the unit tests were all good.

An example:

```
@Test
public void test() {

    tester.startPage(SomePage.class);

    tester.assertComponent("content:form:fields:items:0:component", TextField.class);

    FormTester ft = tester.newFormTester("content:form");

    ft.setValue("fields:items:0:component:input", "test");

    ft.submit();

    tester.assertVisible("content:contactForm:successMsg");

}
```

The "successMsg" is only displayed on success. The test succeeded, whereas in reality it failed, because of some logic that happens in the onInitialize() of the component.

I am now not entirely sure if this is a wicket problem or it is something we do wrong.

Comment: I have a similar thing going on here, where FormTester isn't calling onSubmit() for my form, but not failing either. Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

onInitialize() has nothing to do with form submit. It is called when the component is first attached to a page's component tree.

Take a look at ComponentInitializationIntegrationTest.